# How to restrict access to a site by IP through nGinx?

Tags: nginx, https, dns, debian, ip

I have a website that can be accessed by entering the `IP address`. I want to make it accessible only through the `domain`. There is little suitable material on the Internet, there is no good explanation of what to replace in the ode of the `nginx.conf` file.

In my file already has 2 sections named `server`.

```java
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name avoe.com;
        rewrite ^ https://avoe.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }

server {
        listen                      443 ssl;
        server_name                 avoe.com;
        ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/__reksoft_ru.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private.key;
        ssl_protocols               TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

        client_body_buffer_size         8k;
        client_max_body_size            20m;
        client_body_in_single_buffer    on;
        client_header_buffer_size       1m;
        large_client_header_buffers 4   8k;

        location /Intra/api/thumbor/ {
            proxy_pass http://thumbor/;
        }

        location /solr {
            proxy_pass http://solr;
        }

        location /minio {
            proxy_pass http://minio;
        }

        location /activemq {
            proxy_pass http://activemq;
        }


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://wildfly/;

            proxy_buffer_size 16k;
            proxy_buffers 16 16k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
            proxy_read_timeout 180s;

            proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|DELETE|PUT)$ ) {
                return 405;
            }
        }
```

What to add or replace where so that access is ONLY by domain?

Comment: To avoid to many duplicates on SO, I'm going to delete my answer. The same information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825652/7121513).

Comment: in which block should I write this?

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure the HTTP `Host` header is set to `avoe.com` like this:

```
if ($http_host != 'avoe.com') {
    return 301 https://avoe.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a redirection. As I understand, he want to block an access to the site if the right `Host` header value is missing from the request.

Answer (score 0):

use this config as the server that listens on port 80:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name avoe.com default_server;

    if ($host = avoe.com) {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: in which block should I write this?