# How to stop Nginx redirect if HOST HEADER is incorrect

Tags: nginx

I have been trying to solve this issue for quite awhile now. Bots are hitting my sites hard with INVALID HOST HEADERS and Nginx forwards these requests to Gunicorn/Django. I need to stop them at Nginx. I have tried every solution I can find on SO, and elsewhere, but none seem to work for my setup.

**Nginx.conf**:

```
upstream backend_server {
    server backend:8000;
}

upstream backend_asgi {
    server backend_asgi:8001;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location ~* ^/(api|admin|static|v2) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.site *.example.site;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.site/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend_asgi;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location ~ ^/v2(?:/(.*))?$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/index.html =404;
    }

    location /backend_static/ {      
        alias /backend/assets/;
    }

    location /media/ {      
        alias /backend/media/;
    }

    location ~* ^/(api|admin) {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
        # Set upload size for videos to be 500MB
        client_max_body_size 500M;
    }
}
```

What can i add to my Nginx configuration to stop invalid host headers, given that I have a wildcard subdomain and bots are also using HOST HEADERS w/ subdomains?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825652/7121513) answer.

Comment: Doesn't work. It blocks all traffic.

Comment: It should unless you try to use it in some incorrect way. You need to add `listen [::]:80;` and `server_name example.site *.example.site;` to your first server block. (`server_name example.site *.example.site;` can be replaced with the equal `server_name .example.site;`)

Comment: Added everything you mentioned.. `default_server` directive, `listen [::]:80;`, and `server_name example.site *.example.site;` to my first server block. I also added `return 444` to both server blocks. Site now looks like: `example.site didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: Seems i got the server back up and serving content by removing `return 444` from the `443` https server block. Will see if `return 444` in only the port 80 block works...

Comment: I'm not sure I undrestand correctly what you are actually tried, maybe my answer was so bad written? You need three server blocks in order for this to work: the stub server block (catch-all one) as provided by aforementioned answer, the server block listening on port 80 to serve the requests with the proper `Host` header only and the server block listening on port 443 to serve the requests with the proper `Host` header only.

Comment: You'll need to add `listen [::]:80;` and `server_name .example.site;` lines to the first server block from your question. It won't act as a catch-all server block, it will serve only the proper requests, the catch-all server block should be added additionally.

Comment: I did that but the bots are still getting through. :/